# QML onClicked event isn't launched

Tags: qt, events, qml, signals

I create a QML extension, witch work correctly. But now when i try to launched it with onClicked signal that doesn't work correctly, you can see my code here:

```
QLauncher {
    id: qprocess
}

PlasmaComponents.Label {
    id: label

    visible: showLabel

    anchors {
        top: icon.bottom
        topMargin: units.smallSpacing
        left: parent.left
        leftMargin: highlightItemSvg.margins.left
        right: parent.right
        rightMargin: highlightItemSvg.margins.right
    }

    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

    elide: Text.ElideRight
    wrapMode: Text.NoWrap

    font.pointSize: mouseArea.containsMouse ? 26 : 14

    text: model.display
}

MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true
    onEntered: qprocess.launch('createWaveFromItem "' + model.display + '"')
    onExited: qprocess.launch('createWaveFromItem ""');
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: {
        mouse.accepted = false;
        qprocess.launch('createWaveFromItem "Ouverture"');
    }
}
```

The onClicked is in line number 109.
I see [propagateComposedEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop), so i try to add `propagateComposedEvents: true` and `mouse.accepted = false` but its don't changed anything.

Why it is never launch and how to do it is working ?

Edit : To see all code go to here https://github.com/handyopensource/dvkbuntu-vocalfly

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), mainly _minimal_. Please remove all the unnecessary code and leave only the code that that reproduces the issue.

Comment: it's better now ?

Comment: Ok, try copying and pasting your code and running it. Will you succeed? Probably not. If people wants to help you, how can they test your code?

Comment: No i can't succeed, and all code is here : https://github.com/handyopensource/dvkbuntu-vocalfly.

You need kde and python3 google_speech (`pip3 install google_speech` in Kubuntu, but in Arch it is `pip install google_speech`)

After installation you need to use the plasmoid DVKmenu to test it.

Comment: @PaulWOISARD I comply with all of the above but I do not know how to launch your application, you could detail the procedure. what is DVKmenu?

Comment: I am creating a distribution to help disable people to allow computer access (https://www.dvkbuntu.org/).  It is the menu of our distribution.    

To install the menu you could do  :  
1- Clone the git repository.  
2- Execute install.sh :  
install.sh install in your system:  
  - a script in /usr/bin.  
  - a library and a qmlurl in your system.  
  - a plasmoid in your home directory.  

To use you need add the menu plasmoid of one of your panels.
Example : https://youtu.be/y-tmBbma_0Q  

Voice language is in createWaveFromItem script.

Comment: As others posted, you should provide minimal reproducible example. We are not fortune-tellers, clairvoyant or other kind of psychics. Tho' if i were one I would tell your try to set `z:100` in `MouseArea` component.